# Method for error dataset in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, classification, logistic-regression

If I make Logistic Regression for classification of dog and cat pictures.
but I input human's face picture in this model. Then, this model will classify this picture dog or cat.

How can I handle this wrong data in logistic regression model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model itself cannot detect whether it is a human face or not unless you explicitly train it to recognize human faces.

The logisitic regress model outputs the probability of image being in class A or class B and Prob(Img in Class A) + Prob(Img in Class B) = 1. For a human face, if the difference in predicted probability of both classes is less than some specific threshold, we could label the decision as uncertain one requiring review.

For example, Prob(Class A | image) = 0.9 and Prob(Class B | image) = 0.1, then one can be confident that it is of class A. But say Prob(Class A | image) = 0.45 and Prob(Class B | image) = 0.55, the difference is lower than the previous case and hence, it is more uncertain that it is neither dog nor cat.